# When Enter pressed, button outside modal triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a **login form** on the main page, and a "**create new user**" in a modal. However, when I open the modal and hit enter, the key trigger the login form from behind the modal, and not the *create new user* modal. What can I do to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I was using a form submit on the login form, and click event on the modal form. When I changed both to form submit that behavior was gone. The form tag is something like:

```
<form v-on:submit="createUser" />
```

That's Vuejs. On standard HTML would be something like:

```
<form onSubmit="createUser()">
```

Just a reminder, it's always good to include preventDefault() as @chandowd and @Emersson mentioned.

Comment: Whilst it *is* the Vue way (and congrats for providing a better answer on your own question),  regarding your other example, we should not use inline `on` attribute handlers in *"standard HTML"*. The same way we should not use inline `style` attributes. JS and CSS should be in one place only, ant that's their respective JS, CSS tags or files- not disseminated around HTML files in a hard to debug manner.

Answer (score 0):

You could force the login form to not submit on login. I don't have a lot of information on what stack you're using, but if it's jquery, you could do this.

```
$(document).keypress(
  function(event){
    if (event.which == '13') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
);
```

If you don't use jquery, this idea would still work with other languages...

Comment: *"prevent default when document register Enter"*?? Are you sure that is the right way to tackle that issue? Also, we're humans, not robots, try always to use `KeyboardEvent.key`, not *which* (even though jQuery has standardized it)

Answer (score -1):

try using preventDefault in the form's onSubmit

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added preventDefault but the behavior still persists. That's a good practice though, thank you for the reminder.

Comment: I was actually using submit on the first form, and a click event on the second. When I changed both to submit form, the problem was gone. But that happens even without the prevent. Thank you Emersson